# How to print text from my webpage with high accuracy?

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, printing, gdi

I'm porting a desktop app to the web, this app needs to print text with high precision (< 1 mm) in letter size paper.

The desktop version use the windows GDI api to get the job done. How can I archive the same in the web version?

Can I access the GDI api from my webpage? Or maybe from a chrome extension?

Comment: Relying on an add-on or Windows GDI (which you probably can't use on the web) will limit who can use your page. What are you trying to print? You might be able to use a JavaScript PDF renderer/encoder?

Comment: The clients of the web app will be a small group of people (<50), all of them uses Windows 7, 8 and 10, so the limitation is not a problem. I'm trying to print a form in a pre-printed paper, so it needs to match.

Comment: The PDF option looks good, but i need something more direct, like a print button that sends the job to the default printer

Comment: If you were using IE then you could potentially use VBScript (and maybe even GDI too) but pretty sure chrome wouldn't have anything to do with that. If it's in-house then you might be able to do something server-side to handle all the printing.